# Is there a difference between "Mi havas tekston por korekti" and "Mi havas tekston por esti korekt(a/i)ta"?

Tags: prepositions

*I have a text to correct* seems to be often translated into *Mi havas tekston por korekti* by English Esperanto speakers. I find the translation weird and confusing since a correction is not a goal of the text, but only the goal of me having it. Is it better to translate it as *Mi havas tekston por esti korektata*, since it refers to the object just before "por", or there are no difference between the two translations?

(Note: I also don't like this translation because it does not convey the idea of obligation the English sentence has)

Answer (score 3):

The first sentence with *por korekti* is commonly understood and I would argue correct. "I have a text [in order] to correct". The goal is to do the correction, and in order to do that you have a text.

I would interpret the second sentence as "I have a text [in order] to be corrected". The goal is to be corrected, and in order to do that you have a text.

If you really don't like the first sentence, you can say something like *Mi havas tekston, kiun mi korektos/devas korekti*.

According to the examples at [PMEG](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/i-verboj/kun_rolvortetoj.html#i-13b), it is common for *por* following the object to nonetheless describe the goal of the subject or verb:

- *De du tagoj ŝi ricevis absolute nenion por manĝi* - "To eat" is the goal of "she", not "nothing".
- *malbona loko... kie ne ekzistas akvo por trinki* - "To drink" is not the goal of the water
- *Li tuj sendos al vi en vian domon tutan regimenton por enloĝigi* - "To house" is not the goal of the regiment

Comment: Another alternative is to use the _-end_ ending: “mi havas korektendan tekston”.

Answer (score 1):

I am a native English speaker, but I am confident that *Mi havas tekston por korekti* is correct, based on the model *mi havas multon por fari.* (Which, by the way is one of the more common phrases than needs *por* before the infinitive but fails the "in order to" test taught to English learners.)

It may seem odd to you because there are many sentences of the form "A havas B-on por C-i" which do not have the same semantic relationship as *mi havas multon por fari.*

- mi havis gravan kaŭzon por ŝpari
- [li] ne havas monon por pagi
- mi ne havos tempon por zorgi

Still, there are many which do follow the pattern. That is, in which the object of *havi* is also the object of the infinitive after *por*.

- ili havis nenion por manĝi, (ili povas manĝi nenion.)
- mi ne havis tempon por perdi (ili ne volis perdi tempon.)
- Mi havas nenion por diri, (Li diros nenion.)

*Mi havas tekston por korekti* follows this pattern. (Mi korektos la tekston.)

Finally *Mi havas tekston por esti korektata* is not an expression I would use.